# disabling ng-show on mouseenter not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a registration field with angular in a div that pops over with an error message if it doesn't validate.

```
<div id="email_error_msg" ng-show="email_error_message">
    <span>{{email_error_message[0]}}</span>
</div>
```

What I'd like to happen is that as soon as the user mouses over the error it fades away.

I've tried all the usual jquery but it seems that ng-show will not revert. I've passed the div ng-mouseenter with a method but still nothing. If anyone has any ideas, they'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
<div ng-show=error ng-mouseenter='error=true'>Hide me on mouse over</div>
```

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/jmZy2ToKDkCgVrrCwUDW?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="email_error_msg" ng-show="email_error_message" ng-mouseenter="{email_error_message=0}">
   <span>{{email_error_message[0]}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: could you do jsFiddle?